# constants added to object not constant anymore

Tags: javascript, object, constants

so when i declare a variable and i assign it to an object with some constants in it, all inside a function, it turns out the values aren't constant in the object ??? i tried changing the values of the properties in the console, and they successfully change.

```js
var parent;

/* an anonymous function */

(function () {

   const val = 2;
   const child = {a: 5, b: 'butterball r yumy in tumy :)'}

   parent = {val, child}

}) ();


parent.val = 1; // (val is now 1 ???)
parent.child = [5,7,3]; // (child is now a different object ???)

console.log(parent);
```

Comment: a `const` variable means it cannot be *reassigned*. Bit that its contents cannot be changed.

Comment: yea im not changing the contents of that child, im reassigning it to a whole new array

Comment: Constants are block-scoped, much like variables declared using the let keyword. The value of a constant can't be changed through reassignment, and it can't be redeclared. [more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Comment: You're not reassigning the *variable*. You are reassigning the property `child` which is a completely separate entity. There is no relation between the two. The names just happen to coincide. Is it clearer if you declare it as `const x = {a: 5, b: 'butterball r yumy in tumy :)'}` and then do `parent = {val. child: x)`

Comment: ohh i can see it now ... so the const variables are only pointing to the object, but the object is getting passed on to the parent, so i can edit it ... oopsies

Comment: @mushrombrother.jpg Almost, the object properties are pointing to the value of the constants. The values of the constants cannot be changed, but references to those values can. And the references are what you're changing.

Comment: For better understanding, this is what you have declared - parent = {val: val, child: child}.
You are changing the properties of parent and not const.